# SQL In an EAV model, does the length of the nvarchar matter?

Tags: sql, entity-attribute-value, nvarchar

I'm looking to set up a Entity-Attribute-Value table model, where I want the table to handle various data. I'd like to use `nvarchar(max)`, but I'm worried that it may affect database performance (even though most data will be under 50 chars).

Comment: See : [What's the point of using VARCHAR(n) anymore?](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/whats-the-point-of-using-varchar%28n%29-anymore/) - yes, it does matter - and using all `(n)varchar(max)` is a really really bad design IMHO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in general the defined maximum length of an NVARCHAR column will not affect the performance of the database.  Performance may be impacted by the amount of data *actually* stored in the records, but that will mostly happen if the column is indexed (which it is unlikely to be in an EAV model assuming you're talking about the Value and not the Attribute column.

I say "in general" because you didn't specify which database you're using and it is possible to imagine some storage schemes in which the defined length does make a difference.

Comment: What other db's use `nvarchar`?

Comment: Good point.  (N)VARCHAR, as opposed to VARCHAR is primarily SQL Server (although it will be accepted and mapped to TEXT by SQLite).

Answer (score 2):

Then don't use `nvarchar(max)`; it will be treated as `TEXT`. You're already using a less-than-optimal model. Is there any reason that you can't use `varchar`?

See [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlgetstarted/thread/4d9c6504-496e-45ba-a7a3-ed5bed731fcc) on defined length vs `max`.

Comment: The comment to which you linked (for SQL Server) states that the NVARCHAR(X) and NVARCHAR(MAX) are treated identically as long as the stored text length fits within 8000 characters.  Only values longer than 8000 characters will suffer any performance hit -- and if you have any of those values you need NVARCHAR(>8000) anyway.